# Deploy de Aplicação Django com Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, deploy

fiz uma aplicação Django e estou fazendo uns testes de deploy em uma máquina virtual com Ubuntu Server 18.04, antes de partir para o deploy em um VPS. Fiz as configurações corretamente, mas estou tendo um probleminha o Django não está reconhecendo os templates que estão na pasta templates. Alguém já teve esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: E o template `blog/home` existe?

Comment: existe, ele está na pasta templates

Comment: Ele parece estar tentando carregar em `django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/home.html` dentro do Django instalado. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve] que reproduza o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu settings.py, na variável "TEMPLATES", faça o seguinte:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Tive o mesmo problema utilizando o apache em um servidor dedicado na Hostdime e em um vps na Kinghost, resolvi assim.

Comment: deu certo aqui, muito obrigado ^-^